# How to use onClick() or onSelect() on option tag in a JSP page?

Tags: javascript

How to use `onClick()` or `onSelect()` with `option` tag? Below is my code in which I tried to implement that, but it is not working as expected.

Note: where `listCustomer` domain object list getting in JSP page.

```
<td align="right"> 
  <select name="singleSelect" "> 
     <c:forEach var="Customer" items="${listCustomer}" >
     <option value="" onClick="javascript:onSelect(this);> <c:out value="${Customer}" /></option>
                </c:forEach>
          </select>         
        </td>
```

How do I modify it to detect that an option is selected?

Comment: `<option>` elements don't fire the `click` event in all browsers, you should stray away from relying on this.  Also be careful when tagging, Java != JavaScript, ["Java is to JavaScript what Car is to Carpet."](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/58640/great-programming-quotes/58693#58693)

Comment: @Nick.. using the above code i am creating drop down menu in which customer names are displaying. if i select anyone of the value in drop down menu that value should pass to java script..
Please help me how to do it..

Comment: @Nick.. can you see the below comments i dropped for stephen and i expect your reply for that

Answer (score 119, accepted):

Neither the [`onSelect()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onselect.asp) nor [`onClick()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp) events are supported by the `<option>` tag. The former refers to selecting text (i.e. by clicking + dragging across a text field) so can only be used with the `<text>` and `<textarea>` tags. The `onClick()` event can be used with `<select>` tags - however, you probably are looking for functionality where it would be best to use the [`onChange()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp) event, not `onClick()`.

Furthermore, by the look of your `<c:...>` tags, you are also trying to use [JSP](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/) syntax in a plain HTML document. That's just... incorrect.

In response to your comment to this answer - I can barely understand it. However, it sounds like what you want to do is get the value of the `<option>` tag that the user has just selected whenever they select one. In that case, you want to have something like:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <script type="text/javascript">

   function changeFunc() {
    var selectBox = document.getElementById("selectBox");
    var selectedValue = selectBox.options[selectBox.selectedIndex].value;
    alert(selectedValue);
   }

  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <select id="selectBox" onchange="changeFunc();">
   <option value="1">Option #1</option>
   <option value="2">Option #2</option>
  </select>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Stephen.. using the above code i am creating drop down menu in which customer names are displaying. if i select anyone of the value in drop down menu that value should pass to java script..
Please help me how to do it..

Comment: @Stephen.. i am having more than 1000 customer name ..in that case how can i create option#1,option#2. and also data is dynamic

Comment: In which case, you probably want to populate it server side. Do you use PHP on the server side, or another language?

Comment: @Stephen.. my requirement is i have drop down list menu(displaying in jsp page)  which contains n number of customer names. if i click anyone name in that list that selected name should send to javascript function.
Please provide solution for this..

Comment: Ah, so you're working in Java Server Pages (JSP). Sorry, but that's out of my experience range. I've only used JSP once, and that was for generating just an XML file, not proper HTML. I suggest you google for some tutorials on JSP. Sorry.

Comment: i am creating Lender/Borrower Application, in which as apart of my requirement i have to show all customer names for that Lender in drop down list of jsp page. In that drop down list if i click anyone customer name that name should pass to javascript ..after passing that selected name to javascript i am doing some manipulations..

Comment: **I do not know JSP.** I would suggest, as I said, that you go read some JSP tutorials - it seems like you're fairly unsure how to do something that may be quite simple. Apart from that, your question is now **too vague** for SO - we can answer specific programming questions, but what you are asking now is basically "Please can someone write the code to do this for me."

Comment: The way you're generating the options is fine. What you should do for event handling is to attach a "change" handler to the "select" element, as @Stephen said.

Comment: If you mess around with this page, you'll find that onclick() actually does work, just so long as the size attribute of the select tag is 2 or greater. https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_select_options2

Comment: @Manu how did you solve the problem because I have to do exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 38):

Even more simplified: You can pass the **value** attribute directly!

```
<html>
 <head>
  <script type="text/javascript">

   function changeFunc(i) {
     alert(i);
   }

  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <select id="selectBox" onchange="changeFunc(value);">
   <option value="1">Option #1</option>
   <option value="2">Option #2</option>
  </select>
 </body>
</html>
```

The alert will either return `1` or `2`.

Comment: This could damn well be the accepted answer. It's a good decision to always look at the SECOND answer.

Answer (score 5):

The answer you gave above works but it is confusing because you have used two names twice and you have an unnecessary line of code. you are doing a process that is not necessary.

it's a good idea when debugging code to get pen and paper and draw little boxes to represent memory spaces (i.e variables being stored) and then to draw arrows to indicate when a variable goes into a little box and when it comes out, if it gets overwritten or is a copy made etc.

if you do this with the code below you will see that

```
var selectBox = document.getElementById("selectBox");
```

gets put in a box and stays there you don't do anything with it afterwards.

and

```
var selectBox = document.getElementById("selectBox");
```

is hard to debug and is confusing when you have a select id of  selectBox for the options list . ---- which selectBox do you want to manipulate / query / etc is it the local var selectBox that will disappear or is it the selectBox id you have assigned to the select tag

your code works until you add to it or modify it then you can easily loose track and get all mixed up

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

function changeFunc() {
var selectBox = document.getElementById("selectBox");
var selectedValue = selectBox.options[selectBox.selectedIndex].value;
alert(selectedValue);
}

</script>
</head>

<body>
<select id="selectBox" onchange="changeFunc();">
<option value="1">Option #1</option>
<option value="2">Option #2</option>
</select>
</body>
</html>
```

a leaner way that works also is:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

function changeFunc() {

var selectedValue = selectBox.options[selectBox.selectedIndex].value;
alert(selectedValue);
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<select id="selectBox" onchange="changeFunc();">
<option value="1">Option #1</option>
<option value="2">Option #2</option>
</select>
</body>
</html>
```

and it's a good idea to use descriptive names that match the program and task you are working on am currently writing a similar program to accept and process postcodes using your code and modifying it with descriptive names the object is to make computer language as close to natural language as possible.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function Mapit(){

var actualPostcode=getPostcodes.options[getPostcodes.selectedIndex].value;

alert(actualPostcode);

// alert is for debugging only next we go on to process and do something
// in this developing program it will placing markers on a map

}

</script>

<select id="getPostcodes" onchange="Mapit();">

<option>London North Inner</option>

<option>N1</option>

<option>London North Outer</option>

<option>N2</option>
<option>N3</option>
<option>N4</option>

// a lot more options follow 
// with text in options to divide into areas and nothing will happen 
// if visitor clicks on the text function Mapit() will ignore
// all clicks on the divider text inserted into option boxes

</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

in this example de select tag is named as: aula_clase_cb

```
<select class="form-control" id="aula_clase_cb" >
</select>

document.getElementById("aula_clase_cb").onchange = function(e){
    id = document.getElementById('aula_clase_cb').value;
    alert("id: "+id);
};
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 <div class="form-group">
         <script type="text/javascript"> 
              function activa(){                                                            
                 if(v==0)
                     document.formulario.vr_negativo.disabled = true; 
                 else if(v==1)
                      document.formulario.vr_negativo.disabled = true; 
                 else if(v==2)
                      document.formulario.vr_negativo.disabled = true; 
                 else if(v==3)
                      document.formulario.vr_negativo.disabled = true; 
                 else if(v==4)
                      document.formulario.vr_negativo.disabled = true; 
                 else if(v==5)
                      document.formulario.vr_negativo.disabled = true; 
                 else if(v==6)
                      document.formulario.vr_negativo.disabled = false;}                                                   
        </script> 
        <label>&iquest;Qu&eacute; tipo de veh&iacute;culo est&aacute; buscando?</label>
        <form name="formulario" id="formulario">
          <select name="lista" id="lista" onclick="activa(this.value)"> 
              <option value="0">Vehiculo para la familia</option> 
              <option value="1">Vehiculo para el trabajo</option> 
              <option value="2">Camioneta Familiar</option> 
              <option value="3">Camioneta de Carga</option> 
              <option value="4">Vehiculo servicio Publico</option>
              <option value="5">Vehiculo servicio Privado</option>
              <option value="6">Otro</option>
          </select> 
          <br />
          <input type="text" id="form vr_negativo" class="form-control input-xlarge" name="vr_negativo"/>
        </form>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change selection in the function

```js
window.onload = function () {
  var selectBox = document.getElementById("selectBox");
  selectBox.addEventListener('change', changeFunc);
  function changeFunc() {
    alert(this.value);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Selection</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <select id="selectBox" onChange="changeFunc();">
      <option> select</option>
      <option value="1">Option #1</option>
      <option value="2">Option #2</option>
   </select>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

````
<html>
<head>
<title>Cars</title>
</head>
<body >

<h1>Cars</h1>
    <p>Name </p>
        <select id="selectBox" onchange="myFunction(value);">
            <option value="volvo" >Volvo</option>
            <option value="saab"  >Saab</option>
            <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
        </select>        
<p id="result"> Price : </p>
<script>
function myFunction($value)
{       
    if($value=="volvo")
    {document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "30L";}
    else if($value=="saab")
    {document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "40L";}
     else if($value=="mercedes")
    {document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "50L";}
}
</script>
</body>
</html>```
````

Comment: Code only answers can generally be improved by adding explanation of how and why they work. Ten year old questions with accepted answers can still have answers added, but those answers should point out what new aspect of the question they address.

Answer (score 1):

focus clears value, so select any value is a change and fires myFunc(this) and blur defocus for reselect

```
<html>
 <head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function myFunc(el) {
       //Show option value
       console.log(el.value);
    }
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
   <select id="selectBox" onchange="myFunc(this);this.blur();" onfocus="this.selectedIndex = -1;">
     <option value="1">Option #1</option>
     <option value="2">Option #2</option>
   </select>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is a clever solution for anyone who needs onchange to work when you want to detect when the user selects the currently selected option again.  For example, when the page loads Option #1 is already selected so by definition onchange won't fire when the user selects Option #1.  However it will if you reset the selectedItem to -1 as in the code above on focus.  Neat.

Answer (score 0):

Other option, for similar example but with anidated selects, think that you have two select, the name of the first is "ea_pub_dest" and the name of the second is "ea_pub_dest_2", ok, now take the event click of the first and display the second.

```
<script>

function test()
{
    value = document.getElementById("ea_pub_dest").value;
    if ( valor == "value_1" )
        document.getElementById("ea_pub_dest_nivel").style.display = "block";
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change onClick() from  with onChange() in the . You can send the option value to a javascript function.

```
<select id="selector" onChange="doSomething(document.getElementById(this).options[document.getElementById(this).selectedIndex].value);"> 
<option value="option1"> Option1 </option>
<option value="option2"> Option2 </option>
<option value="optionN"> OptionN </option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to change the value of another field, you can use this:

```
<input type="hidden" id="mainvalue" name="mainvalue" value="0">
<select onChange="document.getElementById('mainvalue').value = this.value;">
<option value="0">option 1</option>
<option value="1">option 2</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

example dom onchange usage:

```
<select name="app_id" onchange="onAppSelection(this);">
    <option name="1" value="1">space.ecoins.beta.v3</option>
    <option name="2" value="2">fun.rotator.beta.v1</option>
    <option name="3" value="3">fun.impactor.beta.v1</option>
    <option name="4" value="4">fun.colorotator.beta.v1</option>
    <option name="5" value="5">fun.rotator.v1</option>
    <option name="6" value="6">fun.impactor.v1</option>
    <option name="7" value="7">fun.colorotator.v1</option>
    <option name="8" value="8">fun.deluxetor.v1</option>
    <option name="9" value="9">fun.winterotator.v1</option>
    <option name="10" value="10">fun.eastertor.v1</option>
    <option name="11" value="11">info.locatizator.v3</option>
    <option name="12" value="12">market.apks.ecoins.v2</option>
    <option name="13" value="13">fun.ecoins.v1b</option>
    <option name="14" value="14">place.sin.v2b</option>
    <option name="15" value="15">cool.poczta.v1b</option>
    <option name="16" value="16" id="app_id" selected="">systems.ecoins.launch.v1b</option>
    <option name="17" value="17">fun.eastertor.v2</option>
    <option name="18" value="18">space.ecoins.v4b</option>
    <option name="19" value="19">services.devcode.v1b</option>
    <option name="20" value="20">space.bonoloto.v1b</option>
    <option name="21" value="21">software.devcode.vpnfree.uk.v1</option>
    <option name="22" value="22">software.devcode.smsfree.v1b</option>
    <option name="23" value="23">services.devcode.smsfree.v1b</option>
    <option name="24" value="24">services.devcode.smsfree.v1</option>
    <option name="25" value="25">software.devcode.smsfree.v1</option>
    <option name="26" value="26">software.devcode.vpnfree.v1b</option>
    <option name="27" value="27">software.devcode.vpnfree.v1</option>
    <option name="28" value="28">software.devcode.locatizator.v1</option>
    <option name="29" value="29">software.devcode.netinfo.v1b</option>
    <option name="-1" value="-1">none</option>
</select>


<script type="text/javascript">

    function onAppSelection(selectBox) {
        // clear selection
        for(var i=0;i<=selectBox.length;i++) {
          var selectedNode  = selectBox.options[i];
             if(selectedNode!=null) {
                  selectedNode.removeAttribute("id");
                  selectedNode.removeAttribute("selected");
            }
        } 
        // assign  id and selected
        var selectedNode = selectBox.options[selectBox.selectedIndex];
        if(selectedNode!=null) {
            selectedNode.setAttribute("id","app_id");
            selectedNode.setAttribute("selected","");
        }
     }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <script type="text/javascript">

    function changeFunction(val) {

       //Show option value
       console.log(val.value);
    }

  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
   <select id="selectBox" onchange="changeFunction(this)">
     <option value="1">Option #1</option>
     <option value="2">Option #2</option>
   </select>
 </body>
</html>
```