# onclick event is not triggered

Tags: javascript

Code:

corresponding function does not executed when clicked

```
<body onload="initialize('2.44','12.331')" onunload="triggerUnLoad()">
        <select>
            <option onclick="initialize('2.44331','2.442211')">-sel places-</option>
            <option onclick="initialize('1.2','1.8')">china</option>
            <option onclick="initialize('1.3','1.2')">brazil</option>        
            <option onclick="initialize('1.4','13.3')">australia</option>
        </select>
```

`Onclick` function is not working

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3487263/how-to-use-onclick-or-onselect-on-option-tag-in-jsp-page

Comment: Perhaps it's an event handler associated with the SELECT element and not OPTION?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In some browsers there is no click event for `<option>` elements. Instead you should use `change` event for `<select>` element:

```
<select onchange="initialize.apply(null, this.value.split(','));">
    <option value="2.44331,2.442211">-sel places-</option>
    <option value="1.2,1.8">china</option>
    <option value="1.3,1.2">brazil</option>        
    <option value="1.4,13.3">australia</option>
</select>
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/SgFKj/

Comment: Working fine as expected. Thanks