# Send values from jsp to Servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

i have a jsp in which i have select tag and i want to get the 
 and the value selected from the select in jsp in my Servlet

```
<select id="listoffood" name="dropdown" onchange="foodname();">
<option value="bg">Burger</option>
<option value="pas">pasta</option>
<option value="pi">pizza</option>
</select>
<div id='content'></div>
```

here is the javascript code

```
function foodname()
{

  var xmlHttpReq = false;
    var self = this;
    document.getElementById('content').innerHtml='';
    // Mozilla/Safari
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        self.xmlHttpReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    // IE
    else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        self.xmlHttpReq = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    self.xmlHttpReq.open('GET', "InformationServlet", true);
    self.xmlHttpReq.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    self.xmlHttpReq.send(null);

    self.xmlHttpReq.onreadystatechange= function ()
    {
        //alert(document.getElementById('content'));
        if (self.xmlHttpReq.readyState==4)
        {
        if (self.xmlHttpReq.status == 200)
        {

        document.getElementById('content').innerHTML=self.xmlHttpReq.responseText;
        }
        }
    };

}
```

What i have done is used a get Attribute like this but it aint working its showing null

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                throws ServletException, IOException 

    {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String coun = request.getParameter("dropdown");
    PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
    System.out.println("here : "+coun);
}
```

Thanks in advance and any piece of code is highly appreciated.

Comment: Will it go to same servlet ??? post your full html form

Comment: what does method `foodName()` do? Is your select inside `form`?

Comment: #kshitj food name goes to javascript and js than calls servlet by ajax.
@Baadshah yes it goes to same servlet on onChange method

Comment: Are you able to get other parameters from this JSP page in your servlet ?

Comment: i dnt have any html form i just have a select tag on my jsp
@AnkitSingla i dont have ant other parameters on my jsp its jusst the select tag

Comment: Post your javascript function, if you are using POST it won't work

Comment: Please post the javascript of the foodName method

Comment: Please, post the code related to the complete flow. Making us guess won't help you as much as we can.

Comment: @AlexandreLavoie i know it wont work with the post method i am using Get method

Comment: i have added the whole code now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your AJAX `open()` request as

```
var select = document.getElementById("listoffood");
self.xmlHttpReq.open('GET', "InformationServlet?dropdown=" + select.options[select.selectedIndex].value, true);
```

Comment: its http://localhost:8080/Distributor/InformationServlet

and its showing an error in the code u gave..
the error is cannot read property 'undefined' of undefined

Comment: nothing is wrong with the url its showing errror in js.. i have mentioned the error in my previous comment

Comment: @AnishSharma Did you try with `var select`.

Comment: yes i did it than shows cannot read property "options" of the undefined

Comment: @AnishSharma I just tested the code and successfully did a GET for `http://www.google.com/search?q=pasta`. Can you do an `alert(document.getElementById("listoffood"));` As per your HTML this shouldn't be `undefined`. Please verify. (two "f"s here)

Comment: Thanks it worked i was making a mistake i commented one line by mistake..
That was all it

Comment: Ah, glad it worked! I was wondering what went wrong since I'd tested my solution successfully. If you found this helpful can you please consider giving an up vote as well.

Comment: i have one more question in case if u r interested in answering.. 
i am posting the link 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16397207/iterate-arraylist-in-jsp

Answer (score 0):

Use method [getParameterValues(String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameterValues%28java.lang.String%29).
This is because `<select>` tag can have multiple selected values (e.g. [select multiple](http://htmlbook.ru/html/select/multiple))

```
String[] coun = request.getParameterValues("dropdown");
```

Comment: I knew somebody will post this. `multiple` is not true for `select`.

Answer (score 0):

Check this post:

[How to use onClick() or onSelect() on option tag in a JSP page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3487263/how-to-use-onclick-or-onselect-on-option-tag-in-jsp-page)

You seems to be using select tag without any action such as onchange

Comment: `onchange=foodname();` I think you missed seeing that!

Comment: @AnishSharma Using a event handler on `select` is fairly common and not the problem here. You don't need to change that.

Answer (score 0):

You can get selected item text from list box using

```
var e = document.getElementById("dropdown");
var selectedValue = e.options[selectBox.selectedIndex].value
```

in your JS method and send this value with servlet's link.

Comment: how can i send the value with servlet link

Comment: InformationServlet?dropdown=selectedValue And use request.getParameter("dropdown");  in your servlet as you have already done.

Comment: <display-name>Distributor</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>InformationServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>requestData.InformationServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>InformationServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/InformationServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>

Comment: @AnishSharma Did you check my answer?

Comment: @AnishSharma :
Have you given the correct package path for <servlet-class> parameter ??

Answer (score 0):

get the value from select tag

```
var e = document.getElementById("dropdown");
var selectedValue = e.options[selectBox.selectedIndex].value;
```

and edit js function

```
self.xmlHttpReq.open('GET', "InformationServlet?dropdown="selectedValue , true);
```

finally  your should looks like

```
function foodname()
{

    var e = document.getElementById("dropdown");
    var selectedValue = e.options[selectBox.selectedIndex].value;

  var xmlHttpReq = false;
    var self = this;
    document.getElementById('content').innerHtml='';
    // Mozilla/Safari
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        self.xmlHttpReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    // IE
    else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        self.xmlHttpReq = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    self.xmlHttpReq.open('GET', "InformationServlet?dropdown="selectedValue , true);
    self.xmlHttpReq.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    self.xmlHttpReq.send(null);

    self.xmlHttpReq.onreadystatechange= function ()
    {
        //alert(document.getElementById('content'));
        if (self.xmlHttpReq.readyState==4)
        {
        if (self.xmlHttpReq.status == 200)
        {

        document.getElementById('content').innerHTML=self.xmlHttpReq.responseText;
        }
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: can you share your web.xml file