# Iterate ArrayList in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, arraylist

I have two arraylists in my class and I want to send it to my JSP and then iterate the elements in arraylist in a select tag.

Here is my class:

```
package accessData;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ConnectingDatabase 
{
   ArrayList<String> food=new ArrayList<String>();
   food.add("mango");
   food.add("apple");
   food.add("grapes");

   ArrayList<String> food_Code=new ArrayList<String>();
   food.add("man");
   food.add("app");
   food.add("gra");
}
```

I want to iterate food_Code as options in select tag and food as values in Select tag in JSP; my JSP is:

```
<select id="food" name="fooditems">

// Don't know how to iterate

</select>
```

Any piece of code is highly appreciated. Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: Are you using any framework or tag libraries ?

Comment: @Santosh sorry i am using struts actually..

Comment: Then [JSTL](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_standard_tag_library.htm) would be good to start with.

Comment: You might want to add `"man"`, `"app"` and `"gra"` in `food_Code` and not `food`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It would be better to use a `java.util.Map` to store the key and values instead of two `ArrayList`, like:

```java
Map<String, String> foods = new HashMap<String, String>();

// here key stores the food codes
// and values are that which will be visible to the user in the drop-down
foods.put("man", "mango");
foods.put("app", "apple");
foods.put("gra", "grapes");

// if this is your servlet or action class having access to HttpRequest object then
httpRequest.setAttribute("foods", foods); // so that you can retrieve in JSP
```

Now to iterate the map in the JSP use:

```jsp
<select id="food" name="fooditems">
    <c:forEach items="${foods}" var="food">
        <option value="${food.key}">
            ${food.value}
        </option>
    </c:forEach>
</select>
```

Or without JSTL:

```jsp
<select id="food" name="fooditems">

<%
Map<String, String> foods = (Map<String, String>) request.getAttribute("foods");

for(Entry<String, String> food : foods.entrySet()) {
%>

    <option value="<%=food.getKey()%>">
        <%=food.getValue() %>
    </option>

<%
}
%>

</select>
```

To know more about iterating with JSTL here is a good [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2117557/how-to-iterate-an-arraylist-inside-a-hashmap-using-jstl) and here is a good [tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_standard_tag_library.htm) about how to use JSTL in general.

Comment: can u please give me the link for JSTL Core jar cuz i have included like 10 jars and its still not recognizing it
It will be really nice of u
Thanks

Comment: Atleast the scriptlet code should work if not `JSTL`? Also did you check if your `Map` contains atleast one element? How are you setting the `foods` map to be accessed in JSP? And here is the link to the zip file which contains the `jstl.jar` & `standard.jar`: http://archive.apache.org/dist/jakarta/taglibs/standard/binaries/jakarta-taglibs-standard-1.0.1.zip

Comment: yes i have printed my map on console and it contains elements and also how can jsp know about the foods map in the class??
And when i use it without jstl that it cannot recognise the Entry and the foods in the code in my jsp..

Comment: JSP would know when you make it know, you have to set the map in either the request scope (`request.setAttribute("foods", foods)`) or the session scope (`session.setAttribute("foods", foods)`) in the servlet class or action class whichever has access to `HttpRequest` object. And in JSP if you are using ELs as I have suggested then its fine but if you are using scriptlets then you need to first fetch the object as I have updated my answer. I would suggest please go through a good tutorial or a good book on JSP/Servlets whenever you get time. It is really essential to understand the workings.

Comment: @Praksh K i am very new to this server side work.still learning its been only a couple of  months.
do share a link for a good tutorial on jsp/Servlets

Comment: @AnishSharma I already have shared it in the answer :-) and the Stackoverflow [tag:jsp] tag wiki is also a very good place to start and grow. Also if you are interested, the book `Head First JSP & Servlets` is a very good book to gain beginner to intermediate level expertise

Comment: that book is amazing Thanks a lot..
but i am still facing problem with my question i have sent my map to jsp using requestdispatcher but still the select tag is empty..
PLease a little help will solve it

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29522/discussion-between-prakash-k-and-anish-sharma)

Answer (score 4):

You can use JSTL's foreach.

```
<c:forEach items="${foodItems}" var="item">
   ${item}
</c:forEach>
```

You need also to import JSTL core:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" 
       uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

Comment: Please post relevant code here, external links might not work in the future, which will make your answer useless.

Comment: @Michal Borek its showing error undefined attribute foodItems

Comment: @Anish Sharma you need to have that item bound to request parameters.

Comment: @MichalBorek `foodItems="${foodItems}"` is not an attribute of `<c:forEach>` it is `items="${foodItems}"`

Answer (score 4):

```
<c:forEach items="${list}" var="foodItem">
 ${foodItem.propertyOfBean}
</c:forEach>
```

This will solve your problem.

Comment: its not recognising the c tag and more over how it will know about the "food" and "food_code" in the java class.

Comment: You have to include following code in the yor jsp file : `<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>`

Comment: You have to include `jstl core tag` library.

Comment: `foodItems=` is not an attribute, `items` is.

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve the list in JSP as

```
<select id="food" name="fooditems">

  <c:forEach items="${listname}" var="food" >

     <option value="${food}"> ${food} </option>

  </c:forEach>

</select>
```

Comment: @venky `foodItems="${foodItems}"` is not an attribute of `<c:forEach>` it is `items="${foodItems}"`

Comment: Am sorry, I missed out. Actually it should be like:  <select id="food" name="fooditems">

      <c:forEach items="${listname}" var="food" >

         <option value="${food}"> ${food} </option>

      </c:forEach>
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways this can be done (with some changes in your scheme)

**Using JSTL:**

1. Create a bean with two fields as `food` and `food_code`

   public class Food{
       private String food;
       private String food_code;
       // Setter/getters follows
   }

Now the arraylist available on the page will be list `Food` objects. 
In the JSP code, you can use following:

```
<select name="fooditems">
    <c:forEach items="${list}" var="item">
        <option value="${item.food_code}">${item.food}</option>
    </c:forEach>
</select>
```

**If you are using struts:**

```
<html:select property="fooditems" >
<html:optionsCollection property="list" label="food" value="food_code" />
</html:select>
```

Here `list` is object key which will be used to retrieve the list from context (page/session)

Comment: i have included struts tag library but its not recognizing the tag html:selecct..

Comment: Have you included the directive at the top (`<%@ taglib  uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-html" prefix="html" %>`) ?

Comment: I assume you included the required jars in the application. Do you see any errors in the log ? How does the generated html source of the jsp look like ?