# How to retrieve Arraylist object in javascript/jsp?

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, servlets

I am developing one sample web application using JSP and Servlets, in this application i have set some object in the Servlets, i can retrieve that value in JSP by using `request.getAttribute("Object")`. Here i want to iterate that array of value in JSP. How can i achieve this any one help me.

**My servlet code**:

```
ArrayList<Performer> Performerobj=new ArrayList<Performer>();
ResultSet rst = stm1.executeQuery("some query"); 
while (rst.next()) 
{   
     Performer obj=new Performer();
     obj.setProject(projectname);
     obj.setCount(rst.getString("COUNT"));
     obj.setDate(rst.getString("DATE"));
     obj.setEmpid(rst.getString("empid"));
     Performerobj.add(obj);
}
request.setAttribute("Performer", Performerobj);
```

**Performer.java**

```
public class Performer {


private String project;
private String empid;
private String date;
private String count;

public String getProject() {
    return project;
}
public void setProject(String project) {
    this.project = project;
}
/*setter and getter...... for all*/
```

**Perform.jsp**

```
    <% List<Performer>obj1=List<Performer>)request.getAttribute("Performerobj"); %>
<script>
       var obj=<%=obj1%>   
for(obj object : list)
{
  /*IS it correct way or how can i iterate*/
}
</script>
```

Comment: Are you getting any error ? Here is one example - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16397207/iterate-arraylist-in-jsp

Comment: In jsp i can use this option, but inside the java script how can i use that method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that if you transform the ArrayList object into a JSON using a library like Jackson:

```
<% List<Performer>obj1 = (List<Performer>) request.getAttribute("Performerobj"); %>
<script>
var obj=<%=new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(obj1)%>;
for(obj object : list)
{
  /*IS it correct way or how can i iterate*/
}
</script>
```

Another option is to use JSTL:

```
<c:forEach var="performer" items="${Performerobj}">
    <c:out value="${performer.project}"/>
</c:forEach>
```