# do Post servlet based DB query results in table format in JSP

Tags: database, jsp, servlets

I have a requirement to display the database query results in a table format in JSP. I have tried various options using forEach and unable to achieve. Can you please help to get the JSP for the DB results from do Post method?

Here is my Servlet

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    doGet(request, response);

    Connection con = null;
    Statement sta = null;
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/cass_db";
    String dbdriver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    String username = "app_user";
    String password = "passwordxxxx";

    try {
        Class.forName(dbdriver);
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
        sta = con.createStatement();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    String Sql = "Select * from doctors";
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    String FileName = "/Users/asia/Downloads/test.log";
    FileOutputStream file = new FileOutputStream(FileName);
    try {
        ResultSet rs = sta.executeQuery(Sql);
        while (rs.next()) {
            file.write(rs.getBytes(5));
            file.write(System.getProperty("line.separator").getBytes());
            list.add(rs.getString("doctor_nric"));
            list.add(rs.getString("doctor_full_name"));
            request.setAttribute("results", list);
        }
        con.close();
        file.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    request.getRequestDispatcher("./DBResults.jsp").forward(request, response);

}
```

}

Database Table structure:

```
doctor_id, doctor_full_name, doctor_login_name, doctor_password, doctor_nric;

1, 'Daniel Ricciardo', 'dany', 'NZQbTKL2Z8pakBcUME3y/A==', 'G6345688X'
```

JSP code here

```
<form action="./DBResults" name="form_DBResults" method="post">
  <label> Click here</label> <input type="submit" value="GetDBResults" id="submitBtn" />
</form>

<table border="1"> 
  <c:forEach items="${results}" var="result">
    <tr>
      <td> <c:out value="${result.doctor_nric}" /></td>
      <td> <c:out value="${result.doctor_full_name}" /> </td>
    </tr>
  </c:forEach> 
</table>
```

The above jsp is not displaying the results in a table format, I am getting HTTP Status 500

> Internal Server Error @ `"<td> <c:out value="${result.doctor_nric}" /></td>"`

If I use `<td> <c:out value="${result}.{doctor_nric}" /></td>` then i get results like `G6345688X.{doctor_nric}` but I am expecting database variable results in table format.

Can you please help to set the DB variable and its equivalent in JSP?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please share the exception stacktrace (from the `logs/catalina.out` file), we need to know the exact exception.

Comment: what error are you getting exactly please post, there are many issues with your code

Comment: I get HTTP Status 500 ? Internal Server Error and message Message javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property [doctor_nric] not found on type [java.lang.String].  Sorry unable to post the complete code.

Comment: Based on the post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29030169/how-to-retrieve-arraylist-object-in-javascript-jsp, I created setters and getter and it is working now.

I welcome any suggestions to improve the code and follow best practices.

Answer (score 0):

You can use display table of jsp. It isn't necessary to use any for.

```
<display:table name="someList" id="row" requestURI="MyAction.do">      
    <display:column property="id" title="identifier"/>  
    <display:column property="description" title="Comments"/>
</display:table>
```