# How to get values from array in jsp

Tags: java, jsp

I want to show the data from an array using JSP.

I have three files:

1. `index.jsp`:

   ```
   <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>

       <head>
           <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
           <title>JSP Page</title>
       </head>
       <body>
           <h1>Hello World! </h1>
           <form name="Input Name Form" action="response.jsp"/>
           <p> Enter your name:</p>
              <input type="text" name="name"/>  
              <input type="submit"   value="ok" />
       </form>

       </body>
   </html>
   ```
2. `response.jsp`:

   ```
   <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
       <head>
           <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
           <title>JSP Page</title>
       </head>
       <body>
           <h1>Hello World!</h1> <br>
           <jsp:useBean id="aaa" scope="page" class="A.a" />
           <jsp:setProperty name="aaa" property="name" value="<%= request.getParameter("name")%>" />
           <jsp:getProperty name="aaa" property="name" />

       </body>
   </html>
   ```
3. `a.java`:

   ```
   public class a {
       public a ()
       {}
       private String name;
   ArrayList() array_list = new ArrayList();


       public String getName() {
           return name;
       }

       /**
        * @param name the name to set
        */
       public void setName(String name) {
           this.name = name;
       //some magic to fill array_list with values

       }
   }
   ```

My question is:

**What statement should I use in jsp to get values from `array_list` in `a.java`?**

I know that there is statement

```
<c:forEach> </c:forEach>
```

but I am not sure how to use it.

Comment: I have edited your question to become more clear and easier to read. Your code was marked as code *and* blockquote (lines that begin with `>`), so I have removed the blockquotes. To get the right indentation within a list, code has to be indented 8 spaces and not just 4, but that's really a detail. I have highlighted inline code and filenames with backticks, removed the ALL CAPS (which can be perceived as rude) and the "thank you", which is not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

A similar question has been asked here: [Iterate ArrayList in JSP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16397207/iterate-arraylist-in-jsp)

Long story short:

```
<c:forEach items="${aaa.array_list}" var="item">
    ${item}
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: doesn't work, for some reason. I just put this snippet in my code but nothing happened. It seems I'm missing something.

Comment: The snippet should only show how to iterate and display the values. Of course you have to replace ${myList} with the real property. In your case ${aaa.array_list} which still won't display anything as you do not fill the list in a.java.

Answer (score 1):

```
<c:forEach items="${dataDetail}" var="data" varStatus="item">
    <c:out value="${data.id}"/>
</c:forEach>
```

Here "dataDetail" is name of the key where you have set your list in controller.

(session  or request ).setAttribute("dataDetail",---List of Data of type Class Data---);

Above code is similar to

```
for(Data data : dataDetail){
   System.out.println(data.getId());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use JSTL.

Try this out:

Have this at top of your JSP:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn" %>  
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
```

And code for displaying data

```
<c:forEach begin="0" end="${fn:length(array_list) - 1}" var="index">
   <tr>
      <td><c:out value="${array_list[index]}"/></td>
   </tr>
</c:forEach>
```