# Displaying an image when selecting an option from a drop down list

Tags: javascript, html, image, html-select

I'm trying to change an image upon selection of an option in a drop down list:

```
function volvoCar()
{
var img = document.getElementById("image");
img.src="volvo.png";
return false;
}
```

And so on for each car.

```
<img id="image" src="Null_Image.png"/>
<select id="CarList">
<option onclick="nullCar()">No Car</option>
<option onclick="volvoCar()">Volvo</option>
<option onclick="audiCar()">Audi</option></select>
```

I can't seem to find anything online that gives me a solution. Whether it's because I'm phrasing it awkwardly or because what I'm trying to do is impossible with javascript, I don't know.

Comment: see this [answer][1] It's Perfect :


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3487274/1460591

Answer (score 2):

Instead of setting the `onClick` event for an option, set the `onChange` event for the select.

HTML

```
<img id="image" src="Null_Image.png" />
<select id="CarList">
    <option value="Null_Image.png">No Car</option>
    <option value="volvo.png">Volvo</option>
    <option value="audi.png">Audi</option>
</select>
```

JavaScript

```
function setCar() {
    var img = document.getElementById("image");
    img.src = this.value;
    return false;
}
document.getElementById("CarList").onchange = setCar;
```

[Here's a working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/treyh/xf2pq/)

Answer (score 1):

Okay, you're doing several things wrong.

1. Your function is called `volvoCar` and you are attempting to use a function called `VolvoCar` - JavaScript is case sensitive.
2. This isn't the best way to assign an event-listener. You're adding it in the HTML, which is considered 'messy' (see [Unobtrusive JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript)). Also, you want to attach the *`function`*, not the result of the function (which you are doing by calling it). Functions are first-class objects in JavaScript.
3. `onclick` is the wrong event handler to use in this case. You want to use the `onchange` handler of the `<select>` element.

So:

**HTML:**

```
<img id="image" src="Null_Image.png"/>
<select id="CarList">
    <option value="Null">No Car</option>
    <option value="Volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="Audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

**JS:**

```
var changeCarImage = function () { 
    document.getElementById('image').src = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value + "_Image.png"
}

var carList = document.getElementById('CarList');
carList.addEventListener('change', changeCarImage, false); // Note this has some issues in old browsers (IE).
```

This can be seen working [here](http://jsfiddle.net/SjHFG/)!