# following jquery doesn't work in chrome while its works in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery

**HTML**:

```
<tr class="txtMult"> 
    <td>2</td> 
    <td>
        <select style="width: 180px;" class="select" id="select2"> 
            <?PHP foreach($results as $row) 
                echo"<option onclick='myAjaxFunction(this);' value=" . $row->itemName .">" . $row->itemName . "</option>"; 
            ?>  
        </select>
    </td> 
    <td><input type='text' class='val1' name="123"></td> 
    <td><input type='text' class='val2' id="2"></td> 
    <td><input type='text' class='multTotal' value='0.00' required></td> 
</tr>
```

**Javascript**:

```
var d = 1;   
function myAjaxFunction() { 
    var string = $('#select' + d + '').val();

    $.post("http://localhost/online_stock_system/new_cont/add", {
        input: string
    }, function (data) {
        $('#' + d + '').val(data);
        // $('#select'+d+'').attr('disabled','');
        d++;
    });  
}
```

this code is included in `new.js` file but it's not working on chrome while it's working on firefox.

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: `wwww.localhost`? I'm guessing cross domain issues, apart from the fact that Firefox accepting 4 w's is just plain wrong.

Comment: try with relative path url

Comment: unrelated but you can change things like `$('#' + d + '').val(data);` to `$('#' + d).val(data);` (without the `+''`)

Comment: <tr class="txtMult">
<td>2</td>
<td><select style="width: 180px;" class="select" id="select2">
    <?PHP
        foreach($results as $row)
            echo"<option onclick='myAjaxFunction(this);' value=" . $row->itemName .">" . $row->itemName . "</option>";
    ?>
 </select></td>
<td><input type='text' class='val1' name="123"></td>
<td><input type='text' class='val2' id="2"></td>
<td><input type='text' class='multTotal' value='0.00' required></td>
</tr>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using `onclick` on an option tag. This is not a supported event. You can see another answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3487274/1400370) for more on that.

If you want the function to trigger when you change the value, just use [`.change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/)

```
$('#select2').on('change', function() {
  myAjaxFunction(this);
});
```

Or

```
$('#select2').on('change', function() {
    var string = $('#select' + d + '').val();

    $.post("http://localhost/online_stock_system/new_cont/add", {
        input: string
    }, function (data) {
        $('#' + d + '').val(data);
        d++;
    });  
});
```