# Javascript Redirect location.href doesn't work in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript

> my javascript based redirect code works well on mozilla and chrome but
>   in internet explorer it doesnt work. here code :

```
<option onclick="location.href='location'">GO</option>
```

**EDIT :**
Error Detection: internet exploer doesn't support onclick event for option tag.

Solvation:

**`HTML:`**

```
<select onchange="redirecttooperator(this);">
<option value="location">GO 1</option>";
</select>
```

**`JS:`**

```
function redirecttooperator(select){
    var operator = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
        window.location.href = operator;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to use onClick() or onSelect() on option tag in jsp page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3487263/how-to-use-onclick-or-onselect-on-option-tag-in-jsp-page)

Comment: who mark -1 point to my question. i have bad words for him. why -1 ?

Comment: I did, Your questions is showing significant lack of research, that is why I down voted it. Please spare me from your bad words, the internet has enough already.

Comment: This also isn't your first question that gets down votes. You need to work more actively on improving your question quality and do basic research before you ask a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML:

```
<select onchange="selectChanged();" id="select">
<option>GO</option>
</select>
```

JS:

```
function selectChanged() {
    var slct = document.getElementById("select");
    var slcted = slct.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
    if(slcted == "GO") {
        window.location.href = "location";
    }
}
```

Comment: internet explorer doesn't support onclick for option tag ?

Comment: thank you your method works i edited it. i write location to value and saved function from a lot of if() statements.

Answer (score -1):

Use window.location instead of location.href

```
 window.location='http://google.com';
```

Comment: It's not supported, see duplicate question

Comment: tried and internet explorer shows script block on browser console