# Selecting multiple value from a dropdown and call a javaScript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

I know I can create a multiple select dorpdown like this -

```
 <select name="city" multiple>
      <option value="Dallas">Dallas</option>
      <option value="New York">New York</option>
      <option value="Kansas">Kansas</option>
      <option value="Massachusetts">Massachusetts</option>
 </select>
```

Using this multiple select dropdown I can select multiple city from. But can I select a javascript method separately for each of the city?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: On the `change` event of select use `.val()` it will return you an array of selected value. then you call your operation

Comment: yes, on select event call a javascript method...get the values by the id and iterate over the selected values.. and call different methods there....

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3487263/how-to-use-onclick-or-onselect-on-option-tag-in-jsp-page

this might help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the value using jQuery '.val()' function.
[Jquery.fn.val()](https://api.jquery.com/val/)

You can see how it works in the following example:

http://jsfiddle.net/uoL3s610/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[name="city"]').change(function(){
        $('#selected_container').text($('[name="city"]').val());
   });
});
```

Or this example

http://jsfiddle.net/uoL3s610/1/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('[name="city"]').change(function(){
    $('#selected_container').text('');
    $.each($('[name="city"]').val(),function(index,value){
        $('#selected_container').text($('#selected_container').text() + ', ' + value)
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are able to store the selected value of your dropdownlist in a variable and then continue with an If-structure or a switch:

```
$("city:selected").each(function () {
    switch($(this).val()){
        case "city1":
        break;
    }
});
```