# Jquery Click select box option not work on Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

I'm having problems in the browser chrome, I want the result of jquery is
"javascript alert", in the mozilla browser no problem.

I use code in
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a8CX6/23/)

```
$('#lang').on('click', 'option', function() {
      alert($(this).val());
 });
```

How to handle it ??

Comment: use the change event of select element, why do you want the click event on the element

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/nbj4LL2h/1/

Comment: @ArunPJohny what if the OP want to alert if it click on the same option twice? change won't fire if the selected option is selected again.

Comment: remove 'option' from $('#lang'). Try in this pattern
$('#lang').on('click', function(){
alert($(this).val());
})

It will invoke onclick function as soon as you click the dropdown.
but it always better to use 'change' instead of click

Comment: I want when click the same option still responds

Comment: @HikmahTiar In my memory it seems there's a similar topic, but unfortunately I just found [how to use onClick() or onSelect() on option tag in jsp page](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3487263/1737627), which says it may not be supported. Anyway, as you're using jquery, consider wrap it with [jQuery.selectmenu](https://jqueryui.com/selectmenu/) or selectable? [jQuery.selectmenu.selected](http://api.jqueryui.com/selectmenu/#event-select) may suit your needs?