# Javascript onselect change price

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to update the price of a product if the user selects an optional extra using a dropdown box. It's supposed to update the hidden field as well as  the H1 tag which shows the user the new price. It doesn't appear to work.

```
function xDeckIncreasePrice(price) {
var total = document.getElementById("agreedPrice").value;
var newprice = Number(total) + Number(price); 
document.getElementById("mixingDeckTotal").innerHTML = "£" + newprice + "";
document.getElementById("agreedPrice").value = "£" + newprice + "";
}
```

Here is the HTML:

```
 <select name="size">
  <option value="6inch">6 Inch</option>
  <option value="footlong" onselect="xDeckIncreasePrice('2.50')">Footlong (+£2.50)</option>
</select>
```

And here are the elements to be updated:

```
<h1 style="color:red;" id="mixingDeckTotal">£4.50</h1><p>
<input type="hidden" id="agreedPrice" value="£4.50">
```

Comment: Seems about right, what's not working?

Comment: It doesn't change the H1 element or the hidden field value

Comment: can you try with this. <input type="hidden" id="agreedPrice" value="4.50">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from using £ in the prices, which won't work for numbers in JavaScript, `<option>` tag does not support `onselect` event. You should use `<select>`'s `onchange` event for that.

Similar question: [How to use onClick() or onSelect() on option tag in a JSP page?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3487263/1223773)

Comment: Thanks this worked however it's returning NaN - the £ symbol isn't factored into the numbers - could it be the decimal causing this?

Comment: Sorry I just saw the £ is in the hidden value. Works great thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should change the onselect event to an onchange event on the actual `select` element itself. You should also change the select options to have a value of the price that the option represents. Then you should change the event you call to just set the text to the value of the option selected.

```js
function xDeckChangePrice(element) {
  document.getElementById("mixingDeckTotal").innerHTML = "£" + element.value + "";
}
```

```html
<select name="size" onchange="xDeckChangePrice(this)">
  <option value="4.5">6 Inch</option>
  <option value="7">Footlong (+£2.50)</option>
</select>

<h1 style="color:red;" id="mixingDeckTotal">£4.50</h1>
```