# Onclick function is not working in Chrome browser

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, cross-browser

This is working fine in Internet Explorer and Firefox but not working in Chrome browser

```html
<select name="Consolidate Report" class="input">
    <option value="">Consolidate Report</option>
    <option value="" onclick="view_graph()">View Graph</option>
    <option value="" onclick="export_graph()">Export Excel</option>
</select>
```

Comment: just show your `view_graph` function..you have an error on `view_graph` function..so it won't alow to execute the function..just only returns `function is not defined`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [onclick on option tag not working on IE and chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9972280/onclick-on-option-tag-not-working-on-ie-and-chrome)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have another suggestion

```
<select onchange="valueChanged(this.value);" name="Consolidate Report" class="input">
        <option value="">Consolidate Report</option>
        <option value="view_graph" >View Graph</option>
        <option value="export_graph">Export Excel</option>
 </select>

        <script> 

         function valueChanged(value){

            if(value == 'view_graph')
            {
                alert('view_graph');
            }else if(value == 'export_graph')
            {
                alert('export_graph');
            }
          }
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`<option>` elements don't fire the click event in most browsers.
you can go with onchange event for select.

http://webbugtrack.blogspot.in/2007/11/bug-280-lack-of-events-for-options.html

[How to use onClick() or onSelect() on option tag in a JSP page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3487263/how-to-use-onclick-or-onselect-on-option-tag-in-a-jsp-page)

Answer (score 0):

Use `onchange()` for `<select></select>` tag instead of `onclick()`.

```js
function view_graph(val){
alert(val);
}
```

```html
<select name="Consolidate Report" class="input" id="x" onchange="view_graph(this.value)">
   <option value="0">--Select--</option>
    <option value="report">Consolidate Report</option>
    <option value="graph">View Graph</option>
    <option value="excel">Export Excel</option>
</select>
```

Comment: it's will work fine but i want to call function directly

Comment: @WebDeveloperPhp you can call the required functions with in the view_graph() based on conditions.