# javascript hide/show function is not working

Tags: javascript, html

This is the basic html page

```
    <div class="col-lg-10">
   <div class="form-group">
       <select class="form-control" id="">
           <option value="" hidden>Select Venue Type</option>
           <option onclick="myFunction()">Theme Restaurant</option>
           <option onclick="myFunction()">Blah restaurant</option>
           <option onclick="myFunction()">Flana Restaurant</option>
           <option onclick="myFunction()">Woops Restaurant</option>
            </select>
            </div>
   <div class="form-group">
  <div class="venue-type" id="restaurant-form">
  <div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-5" id="bsc-edit">
 <div class="form-group">
 <label for="city">Venue Name<sup class = "venue-imp">*</sup>
 </label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="venue-name" placeholder="Jhanqar Banquet Hall" name="name">
  </div>
  </div>
<div class="col-md-1"></div>
<div class="col-md-5">
  <div class="form-group">
  <label for="city">Venue Price<sup class = "venue-imp">*</sup>
</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="venue-price" placeholder="Jhanqar Banquet Hall" name="price">
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-1"></div>
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>
  </div>
```

i want my dropdown list to show a form when clicked and i have tried using javascript function here, but it is not working the form is showing as it is and nothing is working with onclick. Help me to do it as the form is not being shown when clicked but it is shown directly

this is the javascript code;

```
<script>
    function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("restaurant-form");
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
        x.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        x.style.display = "none";
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Did myFunction triggered ?

Comment: Use `change` event handler i.e. `<select class="form-control" id="" onchange="myFunction()">`

Comment: no myFunction didn't triggered

Comment: i want the form to open when a particular dropdown item is selected

Comment: with change event handler on odd item form is showing and on even it is not showing

Answer (score 0):

[onclick is not supported on option tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3487263/how-to-use-onclick-or-onselect-on-option-tag-in-a-jsp-page), You need to add event listener to the `select` instead

```
document.querySelector( "select[id]" ).addEventListener( "change", myFunction );
```

In the `myFunction` method you can show/hide form based on which `option` is selected.

```
function myFunction(event) 
{
  var selection = event.target.selectedIndex;
  var x = document.getElementById("restaurant-form");
  x.style.display = selection >= 1 ? "block" : "none";
}
```

**Demo**

```js
function myFunction(event) 
{
  var selection = event.target.selectedIndex;
  var x = document.getElementById("restaurant-form");
  x.style.display = selection >= 1 ? "block" : "none";
}

document.querySelector( "select[id]" ).addEventListener( "change", myFunction );
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-10">
  <div class="form-group">
    <select class="form-control" id="" >
           <option value="">Select Venue Type</option>
           <option>Theme Restaurant</option>
           <option>Blah restaurant</option>
           <option>Flana Restaurant</option>
           <option>Woops Restaurant</option>
     </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="venue-type" id="restaurant-form">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-5" id="bsc-edit">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="city">Venue Name<sup class = "venue-imp">*</sup>
 </label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="venue-name" placeholder="Jhanqar Banquet Hall" name="name">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1"></div>
        <div class="col-md-5">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="city">Venue Price<sup class = "venue-imp">*</sup>
</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="venue-price" placeholder="Jhanqar Banquet Hall" name="price">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: <select class="form-control" id="restaurant-form"  onchange="myFunction()">

Comment: <script>
    function myFunction(event) {
    var x = document.getElementById("restaurant-form");
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
        x.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        x.style.display = "none";
    }
        document.querySelector( "select[id]" ).addEventListener( "change", myFunction );
}
</script>


with this the form is showing but the drop down hides completely

Comment: @juhi You need to implement hide/show of form based upon your requirement - which you didn't specified in your original question. You need to give it a try and create a new question for new problem.

Comment: i used this
now the problem is when i select the by default value i want the form to hide what to use for that
the default value is "Select Venue" which was earlier hidden but i changed it

Answer (score 0):

Yes as per *@gurvder372* you can't use onclick for option.You can also use an inline event assignment for this Like:

```
 <select class="form-control" id="" onchange="javascript:return myFunction(event);">
           <option value="" hidden>Select Venue Type</option>
           <option>Theme Restaurant</option>
           <option>Blah restaurant</option>
           <option>Flana Restaurant</option>
           <option>Woops Restaurant</option>
</select>
<script>
function myFunction(event) 
{
  var index_opt = event.target.selectedIndex;
  if ( index_opt > 0 ) 
  {
    var x = document.getElementById("restaurant-form");
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
      x.style.display = "block";
    } else {
      x.style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Same problem of odd and even is happening with this too

Comment: what you want exactly to *show*  for on change event of option on a specific option this form is showed

Comment: if want to show on change of select than you simply use `x.style.display = "block";` without if condition.

Comment: Like: `function myFunction(event) 
{
  var index_opt = event.target.selectedIndex;
  var x = document.getElementById("restaurant-form");
  if ( index_opt > 0 ) 
  {
    
    x.style.display = "block";
  }
  else
  {
    
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
  
}`