# I want to calculate total price of subjects given and store it in database

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have no idea how to calculate total price of this subjects using php.
help me with it.

```
<div id="mydiv" style="display:none">   
   <input type="checkbox" name="subject[]" value="biology">biology<br>
   <input type="checkbox" name="subject[]" value="physics">physics<br>
   <input type="submit" value="Calculate" name="submit" class="wpcf7-submit">
</div>

<div id="mydiv1" style="display:none">
   <input type="checkbox" name="subject[]" value="maths">maths<br>
   <input type="checkbox" name="subject[]" value="science">science<br>
   <input type="submit" value="Calculate" name="submit" class="wpcf7-submit">
</div>
```

I want to calculate price total of this checkboxes and store it in database with its names using php

php part

```
if(isset($_POST['subject']))
    {
        $classes=$_POST['subject'];
            $prices = array(
        'biology' => 60,
        'physics' => 200

    );
            $sum = array();
    $getkeys = array_keys($_POST);
    foreach($prices as $key => $value)
    {
        if(in_array($key, $getkeys)) $sum[] = $value;
    }
    $ar=array_sum($sum);
    echo $ar;

        if($classes)
        {

        $subject = implode(',', $ar);

        $query="INSERT INTO feedetails (subjects,price) VALUES ('".$subject."','".$price."')";

        if(mysqli_query($conn,$query))
        {
            echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='Javascript'>
        window.alert('Your fee has been updated.Please proceed to pay.');
        window.location.href='payment.php';
        </SCRIPT>");
        }
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried anything??

Comment: i have tried something.... but it isnt working

Comment: @AshwiniNemade you can share that. something is better than nothing. Don't make us feel that you haven't tried anything

Comment: check update @abhishek

Comment: That's better! :)

Comment: @AshwiniNemade `$getkeys = array_keys($_POST)` this part of code is wrong it will return `subject` not the actual selected subject's

Comment: @AshwiniNemade  Two thing i didn't understand One is `display:none` and why `two form` and which form you are working.

Comment: @AshwiniNemade I have provided an answer, if this resolves your problem please consider marking as the accepted answer. Thanks :)

Comment: @Er.AmitJoshi its because I want to display either one of them after clicking dropdownlist. so I have set it initially to display:none and then run javascript code on each <div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This may be help:

I am not doing all code just you asked for sum part.

Rest you can do Ask if any confusion.

**HTML**

```
<form method='post'>        

    <div id="mydiv" >   
    <input type="checkbox" name="subject[]" value="biology">biology<br>
     <input type="checkbox" name="subject[]" value="physics">physics<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="subject[]" value="maths">maths<br>
   <input type="checkbox" name="subject[]" value="social">social<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="subject[]" value="ssc">ssc<br>


    <input type="submit" value="Calculate" name="submit" 
    class="wpcf7- 
   submit">
   </div>
```

**PHP**

```
   <?php
      $classes =$_POST['subject'];

        $prices = array('biology' => 60,'physics' => 
              200,'maths'=>100,'ssc'=>40,'social'=>150);
        $sum = 0;

        echo 'Subject::Price<hr/>';
        foreach($classes as $key=>$sub){

           if(array_key_exists($sub,$prices)){
            echo $sub.'::'.$prices[$sub]."<br />";
            $sum = $sum+$prices[$sub]; 
           }
      }
       echo '<hr/>';
      echo $sum;
     ?>
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: @AshwiniNemade can you post your complete code at `pastebin` website . Share the `pastebin` link

Comment: i dnt have account on pastebin... i have copied exact same code of yours..... no changes done in it. still not working

Comment: `pastebin` is a free website no need of the registation. simply follow the drop down menu   @AshwiniNemade   https://pastebin.com/

Comment: @AshwiniNemade i am not blaming you some time silly mistakes happens :) rest is your wish. Thanks

Comment: Thanks For Your Vote :)

Comment: @AshwiniNemade I have a query `is your javascript **onclick** event is working with option tag of select element`. I mean after click is `myFunction`and `myFunction1` properly working?

Comment: @AshwiniNemade  Read This answer that's why i am little confused. 
[READ THIS POST](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3487274/9128487)

Answer (score 1):

It appears that your summing strategy was not working, there were numerous issues there including this:

`$getkeys = array_keys($_POST);`

which *appears* as an attempt to get the subjects submitted, however they are in their own sub-array of `$_POST`, i.e. `$_POST['subject']`

This gets you the summing of the price information you require, however you will need to test your database `INSERT` code and debug this to ensure you are storing the data required correctly.

```
if (!empty($_POST['subject'])) {
    $prices = [
        'biology' => 60,
        'physics' => 200,
        'maths' => 300,
        'science' => 400,
    ];
    $sum = 0;

    foreach ($_POST['subject'] as $subject) {
        if (!empty($prices[$subject])) {
            $sum += $prices[$subject];
        }
    }
    echo '<pre>';
    echo '$sum ' . print_r($sum, true);
    echo '</pre>';
    exit;

    // process database inserts here
}
```

Additionally, when testing your code I notice you had hidden the checkboxes, to resolve this, use the following:

```
<div id="mydiv">   
    <input type="checkbox" name="subject[]" value="biology">biology<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="subject[]" value="physics">physics<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="subject[]" value="maths">maths<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="subject[]" value="science">science<br>
    <input type="submit" value="Calculate" name="submit" class="wpcf7-submit">
</div>
```

Comment: not working! cannot display total price ...i copied exact same code

Comment: @AshwiniNemade oh yes it is... http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/fa6dbb7300f40d4f1d4cef51adbf18fe057d61bf