# onclick not working on chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, firefox

This is my code where onclick function is mentioned. This code works fine on firefox but it doesnt work on chrome. the onclick function is working on firefox i.e when i click on degree it displays the checkbox but when i run this same code on chrome it is not displaying the checkboxes.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("mydiv");
  var y = document.getElementById("mydiv1");

  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";

    y.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}

function myFunction1() {
  var x = document.getElementById("mydiv1");
  var y = document.getElementById("mydiv");

  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";

    y.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<select>
    <option value="Degree" onclick="myFunction()">Degree</option>
    <option value="Diploma" onclick="myFunction1()">Diploma</option>
</select>
<div id="mydiv" style="display:none;">
  <div>
    <label class="switch">
            <input type="checkbox" name="subject[]" value="Subject-1" id="myCheck" onclick="Function()">
            <span class="slider"></span>
        </label> Subject-1
  </div>
</div>
<div id="mydiv1" style="display:none;">
  <div>
    <label class="switch">
            <input type="checkbox" name="subject[]" value="Subject-1" id="myCheck" onclick="Function1()">
            <span class="slider"></span>
        </label> Subject-1
  </div>
</div>
```

Any suggestions? How can this code work on chrome?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use onClick() or onSelect() on option tag in a JSP page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3487263/how-to-use-onclick-or-onselect-on-option-tag-in-a-jsp-page)

Comment: no onchange is not working either... I tried this earlier

Comment: Hello :). What does "does not work" mean? Doesn't it trigger? Does it act weird? Are there errors in your dev console? Ah, and `option` needs to be a child of `select`.

Comment: Let me guess, you changed this to `<option onchange="...">` now …? Nah, just kidding - **don’t** let us guess, but show us exactly what you tried. Please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Why do you have `option`s without a `select` element?

Comment: yes I changed it to <option onchange="myFunction();">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You edited it now, but at the beginning you where missing that a `option` element has to be child of a `select` element.

To your second problem:

You can't fire functions using `onclick` and `onchange` on `option` elements. You could fire a function by adding `onchange` on your `select` that fires, based on the input, either `myFunction()` or `myFunction1()` like this:

```js
function someFunction() {
  var select = document.querySelector('select');
  var option = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;

  if (option == "Degree") {
    myFunction();
  } else if (option == "Diploma") {
    myFunction1();
  } else {
    document.getElementById('mydiv').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('mydiv1').style.display = "none";
  }
}

function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("mydiv");
  var y = document.getElementById("mydiv1");

  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";

    y.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}

function myFunction1() {
  var x = document.getElementById("mydiv1");
  var y = document.getElementById("mydiv");

  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";

    y.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<select onchange="someFunction()">
  <option>Select something</option>
  <option value="Degree">Degree</option>
  <option value="Diploma">Diploma</option>
</select>
<div id="mydiv" style="display:none;">
  <div>
    <label class="switch">
            <input type="checkbox" name="subject[]" value="Subject-1" id="myCheck" onclick="Function()">
            <span class="slider"></span>
        </label> Subject-1
  </div>
</div>
<div id="mydiv1" style="display:none;">
  <div>
    <label class="switch">
            <input type="checkbox" name="subject[]" value="Subject-1" id="myCheck" onclick="Function1()">
            <span class="slider"></span>
        </label> Subject-1
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @AshwiniNemade Glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

The cause is your bad script type. In actual fact it'd work without the attribute, but otherwise change it to:

```
 <script type="application/javascript">
    function myFunction() {
      var x = document.getElementById("mydiv");
      var y = document.getElementById("mydiv1");

      if (x.style.display === "none") {
          x.style.display = "block";

          y.style.display="none";
      } else {
          x.style.display = "none";
      }
    }
    function myFunction1() {
      var x = document.getElementById("mydiv1");
      var y = document.getElementById("mydiv");

      if (x.style.display === "none") {
          x.style.display = "block";

          y.style.display="none";
      } else {
          x.style.display = "none";
      }
    }
 </script>
```