# How can I change the color of a Glyphicon?

Tags: javascript, html, css

A couple of days ago, I asked if it was possible to have a change in a certain drop-down list invoke an action: [Javascript/CSS: dynamically change border color of HTML element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51175690/javascript-css-dynamically-change-border-color-of-html-element)

I was correctly pointed to the on-change listener. I got that to work with standard buttons, but can't change the style color of a bootstrap glyphicon. Does that require some additional code?

This is the Javascript code:

```
<script>
function highlightUpdateIntervalProfile{{$profile->id}}() {

var button1 = document.getElementById("buttonAck{{$profile->id}}");
var button2  = document.getElementById("buttonAck");

button1.style.color = "red";
button2.style.color = "red";
}
</script>
```

This is the (Laravel blade) button:

```
{{Form::button('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-save" style="color:blue"></i>', array('type' => 'submit', 'class' => '','id' => 'buttonAck'.$profile->id))}}
    {!! Form::close() !!}
```

I do get the button via the document.getElementById("buttonAck{{$profile->id}}") action but can't change the color. The color of the second button is changing.
Anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to create this config in css:

```
html .btn-blue {
   color: blue !important;
}
```

And make your event add class `btn-blue` in your element. If it does not work, try replacing the sets of settings that leave the element of another color in the css.

Answer (score 1):

Do color changes appear in styles on Inspect Element in the browser? If yes and if the properties are trimmed, you need to add the `!important` property in css. Example of how it would look:

```
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-save" style="color:blue !important"></i>
```

Try changing to:

```
<script>
function highlightUpdateIntervalProfile{{$profile->id}}() {

var button1 = document.getElementById("buttonAck{{$profile->id}}");
var button2  = document.getElementById("buttonAck");

button1.style.color = "red !important";
button2.style.color = "red !important";
}
</script>
```

I forgot to put the modified code :)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment. I checked if the style of the glyphicon and it didn't change. The style of the other button did change to red. Well, I did learn something :-) so that's nice.

Comment: Try to set style with css classes. Create class: 
    
    html .btn-blue {
     color: blue;
     }

Since 'html' is the root element, your property will have priority. Make your event add the class 'btn-blue' in your element.