# JS function never being called but others do

Tags: javascript

I have the following select on my JSP file:

```
            <select id="order-select">
                <option value="Lowest price" onclick="sortLowestPrice()"><spring:message code="list.lowest"/></option>
                <option value="Highest price" onclick="sortHighestPrice()"><spring:message code="list.highest"/></option>
            </select>
```

Turns out I never get to call sortLowestPrice() or sortHighestPrice(). 
I know my JS works because other functions on it get called in the same JSP and they work fine.

Here's one of those functions:

```
function sortHighestPrice() {
    console.log("im here");
  var publications = document.querySelectorAll(".polaroid-property");
  var sort = [];
  var father = document.getElementById("publications");
  var i, j, k;
  var max = null;
  while (father.firstChild) {
        father.removeChild(father.firstChild);
  }
  for(i = 0; i < publications.length; i++){
    max = null;
    for(j = 0; j < publications.length; j++){
        if(publications[j].getAttribute("visited") != "true"){
            var price = parseInt(publications[j].getElementsByClassName("price-tag")[0].innerHTML.substring(1));
            if(price > max || max == null){
                max = price;
                k = j;
            }
        }
    }
    sort.push(k);
    publications[k].setAttribute("visited",true);
  }
  for(i = 0; i < sort.length; i++){
    publications[i].setAttribute("visited",false);
    father.appendChild(publications[sort[i]]);
  }
}
```

I never get 'im here' on the browser log.

Comment: Are there any JS errors reported in the browser log when the page loads or the button is clicket?

Comment: I think this is your answer: "Neither the onSelect() nor onClick() events are supported by the <option> tag." from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3487263/how-to-use-onclick-or-onselect-on-option-tag-in-a-jsp-page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of trying to listen for click events on each `<option>`, you can listen for a change event on the parent `<select>` tag and retrieve the value of the selected option from the DOM event object inside of your function. See below:

```js
function sortHighestPrice(e) {
    var optionValue = e.target.value;
}
```

```html
<select onchange="sortHighestPrice(event)" id="order-select">
  <option value="Lowest price" onclick="sortLowestPrice()">
    <spring:message code="list.lowest"/>
    option1
  </option>
  <option value="Highest price"         onclick="sortHighestPrice()">
    <spring:message code="list.highest"/>
    option2
  </option>
</select>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your browser does not support onclick on the option element. Try using another element type such as a button (ie something that is guaranteed onclick support)

This is an issue I have run across with chrome.

Answer (score -1):

You can see on w3schools [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_option.asp)  that the `option` tag does not support `onSelect()` or `onClick()`

Further details on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3487263/how-to-use-onclick-or-onselect-on-option-tag-in-a-jsp-page) Stackoverflow question outline an alternative approach, as my comment above mentions.

Comment: Please don't post link-only answers to other Stack Exchange questions. Instead, include the essential portions of the answer here, and *tailor the answer to this specific question.*