# Jump menu with onclick function

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu

I want to integrate a link with an onclick event to a function like `<a href="#" onclick="fireMarker(1);">Map Marker URL 1</a>` and `<a href="#" onclick="fireMarker(2);">Map Marker URL 2</a>` into a jump  menu like

```
<select id="selectbox" name="" onchange="javascript:location.href = this.value;">
    <option value="https://www.yahoo.com/" selected>Option1</option>
    <option value="https://www.google.co.in/">Option2</option>
    <option value="https://www.gmail.com/">Option3</option>

</select>
```

OR

```
<select onchange="fireMarker(this);">
    <option value="15">1</option>
    <option value="16">2</option>
    <option value="18">3</option>
</select>
```

The fireMarker function is:

```
 function fireMarker(id){
                    google.maps.event.trigger(markers[id], 'click');
                    markers[id].setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.DROP);
                    markers[id].setVisible(true);
                    }
```

When I click an option I want it to execute urls in the format Map Marker URL.
I hope to have multiple jump menus on same page
Thanks

Comment: taste this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3487263/how-to-use-onclick-or-onselect-on-option-tag-in-a-jsp-page/16432178

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace onchange="fireMarker(this); with onchange="fireMarker(value)"

like:

```
<html>
<head>  
<script type="text/javascript">
    function fireMarker(id) {
        google.maps.event.trigger(markers[id], 'click');
        markers[id].setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.DROP);
        markers[id].setVisible(true);
   }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <select onchange="fireMarker(value)">
        <option value="15">1</option>
        <option value="16">2</option>
        <option value="18">3</option>
    </select>
</body>
```

Comment: Awesome. Worked perfectly. You rock! :)