# onClick event handler not being applied to a styled component

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

In the code I have applied an onClick event handler on the **Option** component which triggers the **noBorder** function on clicking , but on clicking the function does not work as I do not get 'hello' in console. However on applying the same event handler in the **Container** component works. Can anybody tell where I am going wrong please.

```
const Navbar = () => {
  const noBorder = (e) => {
    // e.preventDefault();
    // e.currentTarget.style.border = "none";
    console.log("hello");
  };
  return (
    <Container>
      <LogoWrapper>
        <Logo src={logo} alt="image not found"></Logo>
      </LogoWrapper>
      <LanguageSelector>
        <GlobeIcon src={globe} alt="image not found" />
        <label htmlFor="language">
          <LanguageButton name="language">
            <Option value="english" onClick={noBorder}>
              placeholder
            </Option>
            <Option value="hindi" onClick={noBorder}>
              placeholder
            </Option>
          </LanguageButton>
        </label>
      </LanguageSelector>
    </Container>
  );
};
const Container = styled.div`
`;
const Logo = styled.img`
`;
const LogoWrapper = styled.div`
`;
const LanguageButton = styled.select`
`;
const Option = styled.option`
`;
const GlobeIcon = styled.img`
`;
const LanguageSelector = styled.div`
`;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`option` is a special HTML tag that is rendered as part of `select`, so interaction and styling is very limited. It has nothing to do with `styled-components`, since props are just passed on. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3487263/how-to-use-onclick-or-onselect-on-option-tag-in-a-jsp-page) for a more in-depth answer.

Comment: Ok,can you help me with the following problem, whenever I select a option a white border emerges on the <select> component it only disappears when I click else where is there a way to fix this so that it does not appear in the first place